# Regex pattern incorrect and combination

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have regex pattern like below:

```
Regex rx1 = new Regex(@"<div>/\*(.(?!\*/))*\*/(</div>|<br/></div>|<br></div>)");
Regex rx2 = new Regex(@"/\*[^>]+?\*/(<br/>|<br>)");
Regex rx3 = new Regex(@"/\*[^>]+?\*/");
```

Can anybody help to join together the regexes become 1 pattern?

Comment: Yes, you can combine the patterns but it will become unwieldy unless you comment it with free spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with RX1 is because of `(.(?!\*/))*\*/` which captures any character zero or more times aslong as it is not followed by `*/` because of this the answer can never match.

**UPDATED Answer**

```
@"(?'div'<div>)?/\*((?<!\*/).)*?\*/(?:<br/?>)?(?'-div'</div>)?(?(div)(?!))"
```

This will capture:

```
 (?'div'<div>)    an optional opening div stored in capture group div
 /\*              char sequence /*
 ((<!\*/).)*?     zero or more characters, non greedy and each character is not 
                  preceded by the string */
 \*/              char sequence `*/`
 (?:<br/?>)?      optionally <br> or <br/>
 (?'-div'</div>)? optionally </div> remove from capture group `div`
 (?(div)(?!))     match only if capture group div is empty (ie balanced <div> </div>)
```

Comment: Thx, but i found a problem. when your code apply like <div>/*dfd*/......<br/><div>...</div><div>/*...*/<br/></div>. it will remove all the contents between first div to last div. i need it check each /*..*/ inside div. if this div only contains /*..*/, no any other things beside <br/> or <br> then remove whole div. if not just remove /*..*/.

Comment: means <div>/*dfd*/....../*kkk*/<div>. i need to keep the contents and div away, i just need to select /*dfd*/ and /*kkk*/. if <div>/*sds*/</div> or <div>/*sds*/<br/></div>, then select all include div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this for combining the patterns:
`(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3)` means `pattern1 or pattern2 or pattern3`

Comment: It's working for combination, how about <div>/\*(.(?!\*/))*\*/(</div>|<br/></div>|<br></div>) still can't get the result that i need. it din check <div>. any idea from you? thx

Answer (score 0):

Try the following(It's frankenstein code but it helps you manage each regex variable as it's own as opposed to concatenating all three into one big regex(although that it is not wrong but it can be hard to manage changes to the regex).:

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BatchRegex
{
    class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] target = 
    {

            "<div>/*...*/</div> <div>/*...*/<br></div> <div>/*...*/<br></div>",
            "/*...*/<br></div> or /*...*/<br/></div>"

    };





        foreach (var tgt in target)
        {
           var rx1 = new Regex[]{new Regex(@"<div>/\*(.(?!\*/))*\*/(</div>|<br/></div>|<br></div>)", RegexOptions.Multiline),
            new Regex(@"/\*[^>]+?\*/(<br/>|<br>)", RegexOptions.Multiline),
            new Regex(@"/\*[^>]+?\*/", RegexOptions.Multiline)};


            foreach (var rgx in rx1)
            {
                var rgxMatches = rgx.Matches(tgt).Cast<Match>();

                Parallel.ForEach(rgxMatches, match =>
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Found {0} in target {1}.", match, tgt);

                    });
            }
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}